# Can any one point out mistakes in this code? prepared statement

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

This might e a piece of cake for some of you people, but for me it's a challenge.
I am trying to work with security in mind, and since I am new to PHP and Mysql I can never be 100% sure of my work. So can any one spot mistakes in this code?

```
$sql = 'SELECT caracteristique_id, caracteristique, obligatoire FROM caracteristique WHERE categorie = ?';


if(mysqli_prepare($con, $sql)){
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $cat);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $row = array();
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row['caracteristique_id'], $row['caracteristique'], $row['obligatoire']);

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
// do stuff here
}
}
```

Any help would and will e appreciated.
N.B. I did a lot of research on the net, I am just not sure 100%.

Comment: Please show the layout of the table `caracteristique`.

Comment: Actually it contains many columns but for the sake of brievty I mentioned only two. nothing special about the other cols

Comment: You mentioned three and `caracteristique` stands out, because it is the table name as well.

Comment: yes there are three. the table name is caracteristique and it does contain a column caracteristique. Sorry! I am not used to ask question on the net... one should be careful and proofreads his question. Sorry again for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can (optimise/rewrite) the code segment (It'll be more ORMised):

```
$sql = 'SELECT caracteristique_id, caracteristique, obligatoire FROM caracteristique WHERE categorie = ?';
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
if( $stmt ) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $cat);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = array();
    $stmt->bind_result( $row['caracteristique_id'], $row['caracteristique'], $row['obligatoire']);
    while( $stmt->fetch() ) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Other than that, I don't think there are any issues with the segment at all. It should work fine.

---

As for errors etc, put the above segment inside `try-catch` block:

```
try { 
    /* The segment from above */
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
    echo $e->errorMessage(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks, but What is ORMised? and also, I guess this is OOP style, no?

Comment: besides how about a hint as for exceptions or errors?

Comment: @user3134422 [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). As for errors, put the entire segment above in a `try-catch` block.

Comment: After a it of trial and error, I figured out that ($stmt->fetch()) needs no parameters.

Comment: Ah damn! I forgot to remove it from there. Sorry @user3134422